# all apps open with admin permissions for all users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-permissions

this is on a Virtual Machine running WIN2008 R2 Enterprise:

When users login and open programs, the programs always open with elevated permissions and application's title bar has " (Administrator)" appended to the app title.

If I click on properties of the executable and go to compatibility tab, the "Run this program as an administrator" is not checked.

What else can I check and how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Someone has likely disabled [UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7) and your users must also all be members of the Administrators group which is probably the reason one of them was able to disable UAC in the first place.